# Error "The requested domain already exists in Azure database." while purchasing domain on Azure

Tags: azure, dns

I got this error while trying to purchase a domain on Azure -

[image]

Anyone knows what are the reasons which can cause this, or how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error shows that the domain name already exists, you can change to select another available domain name. The domain name is a global name which should not conflict with others.

Comment: The domain I was trying to purchase seems to have been already taken. I tried a different domain and it worked seamlessly :)